# Can't login after migration

Tags: users

I moved my website from my computer to another one, I moved drupal folder and the database with `backup & migrate`, I used to do it every day and now on the first call, The website worked, but after login with admin, I can't acces the website.
I tried changing `$cookie_domain`, but it was already commented, also `rewrite_module` is enabled on apache, I'm workin on localhost. help me guys, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [drush upwd](https://www.drupal.org/node/44164) to reset your password

`drush upwd --password="givememypasswordback" "admin"`

If you don't have drush installed do it via MySQL. [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428) is a related article.

Comment: thank you for responding, i tried but it's not working , after reseting the pass, i can't acces to the site ,thank you

Comment: how about drush uli admin? resources on recovering the administration password https://www.drupal.org/node/44164

Comment: @Aymen Did you try the MySQL way ? Are you sure you are typing your password correctly ? Lastly try the one-time-login link drush uli (like mentionted above) and check your email.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can create another account, copy its hash to user 1 and then use its password. Or use backup migrate.